HowTo: Create type safe cross pydantic version compatible config mixins
Description
We have started to add support for pydantic v2 in our distributed MLops platform. A core challenge we are currently facing, is that pydantic is literally part of every single python package in our platform and used for various use cases:

microservices running fastapi + pydantic
configuration management for training + processing jobs
modeling structured log payloads
and more

Our core issue is, that we need to support both versions for an unknown period. That is mainly, because there are ML models that have been trained with pydantic v1 and need to be served with v1, while there might be new ML models trained with v2 that also need to be served with v2. At runtime, especially in our ML endpoints, we might have either v1 or v2 installed, and we need to be able to support both.
This brings us into a position where some components of our platform will need to be compatible with both versions for an unknown time (could be weeks, months, ...). This creates the need to provide a cross version compatibility layer that makes transition easier.
While we have been able to get most utilised pydantic features test and type safe cross version (using some sort of wrapper/adapter code), pydantic model configuration is a thing which still bothers us. This is because there might be hundreds/thousands of places where base models are persisted in code with different configuration settings (mutable or immutable, with aliasing or without, with extras or without, etc.).
To ease this transition, we have thought about creating cross version compatible mixin classes that can be requested to create configured pydantic models. This is somewhat the idea:
# type checking this code does work via something like `python -m mypy foo.py --always-true PYDANTIC_V1`
import packaging.version
import pydantic

PYDANTIC_V1 = packaging.version.parse(pydantic.__version__).major == 1

if PYDANTIC_V1:
    class Immutable(pydantic.BaseModel):
        """mixin to make a pydantic model immutable"""

        class Config:
            allow_mutation = False
else:
    from pydantic import ConfigDict


    class Immutable(pydantic.BaseModel):
        """mixin to make a pydantic model immutable"""

        model_config = ConfigDict(frozen=True)


To make a model immutable, our customers could then just simply declare their models this way:
from foo import Immutable

class JobConfiguration(Immutable):
    foo: str

However, this becomes tricky with multiple inheritance. We have tried two possible approaches with v1, which both fail type checks with the pydantic mypy plugin
Approach No 1 (using Config classes)
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Immutable(BaseModel):
    """mixin to make a pydantic model immutable"""

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False


class WithAliases(BaseModel):
    """mixin to make a pydantic model to accept and serialize by alias"""

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

    def json(self, by_alias: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        return super().json(by_alias=by_alias, **kwargs)


class Customer(Immutable, WithAliases):
    id_: str = Field(..., alias="id")


instance = Customer(id_="foo")
instance.id_ = "1"

Running mypy on this code fails
python -m mypy v1.py --always-true PYDANTIC_V1 
v1.py:23: error: Definition of "Config" in base class "Immutable" is incompatible with definition in base class "WithAliases"  [misc]
v1.py:28: error: Property "id_" defined in "Customer" is read-only  [misc]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Approach No 2 (using class kwargs)
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Immutable(BaseModel, allow_mutation=False):
    """mixin to make a pydantic model immutable"""


class WithAliases(BaseModel, allow_population_by_field_name=True):
    """mixin to make a pydantic model to accept and serialize by alias"""

    def json(self, by_alias: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        return super().json(by_alias=by_alias, **kwargs)


class Customer(Immutable, WithAliases):
    id_: str = Field(..., alias="id")


instance = Customer(id_="foo")
instance.id_ = "1"


Running mypy on this code fails as well, albeit with different error messages
python -m mypy v2.py --always-true PYDANTIC_V1
v2.py:21: error: Unexpected keyword argument "id_" for "Customer"; did you mean "id"?  [call-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Does anyone know of a way to use multiple configuration mixin classes in pydantic v1 and have them pass mypy type checks?
System Details
Virtualenv
Python:         3.10.14
Implementation: CPython

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix

Dependencies
mypy              1.9.0
mypy-extensions   1.0.0
packaging         24.0
pydantic          1.10.10
tomli             2.0.1
typing-extensions 4.11.0

mypy configuration
[tool.mypy]
plugins = [
  "pydantic.mypy"
]
strict = true
implicit_reexport = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
check_untyped_defs = true
show_error_codes = true
warn_redundant_casts = true
warn_unused_configs = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
# for strict mypy: (this is the tricky one :-))
disallow_untyped_defs = true

[tool.pydantic-mypy]
init_forbid_extra = true
init_typed = true
warn_required_dynamic_aliases = true
warn_untyped_fields = true


This is a follow up issue from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78334657/how-to-run-mypy-on-3rd-party-package-version-sensitive-code
I've also asked here:
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/9309
